# getting error whille filtering kafka messages with postgresql field type text

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=ptl_connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:320)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:245)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.debezium.DebeziumException: Error while evaluating expression 'value.after.brandid == BrandA' for record 'SourceRecord{sourcePartition={server=testdev_ptl005}, sourceOffset={last_snapshot_record=false, lsn=27649944, txId=707, ts_usec=1594357573069000, snapshot=true}} timestamp=null, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=)}'
at io.debezium.transforms.scripting.Jsr223Engine.eval(Jsr223Engine.java:116)
at io.debezium.transforms.Filter.doApply(Filter.java:33)
at io.debezium.transforms.ScriptingTransformation.apply(ScriptingTransformation.java:189)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
... 11 more
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BrandA for class: Script1
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320)
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71)
at java.scripting/javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:89)
at io.debezium.transforms.scripting.Jsr223Engine.eval(Jsr223Engine.java:107)
... 16 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BrandA for class: Script1
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:65)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:51)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:341)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317)
... 19 more

Comment: Hi, please provide the _FULL_ stacktrace of the error. Without it it is impossoble to diagnose the problem. Just for starter have you added the scripting language JARs on the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please place JAR files to the connector (so debezium-connector-*) directory

- groovy-3.0.4.jar
- groovy-jsr223-3.0.4.jar
- groovy-json-3.0.4.jar

Comment: I got the same error after placing jar file "groovy-3.0.4.jar" in kafka/libs/

Comment: I am sory, I edited my response as I described procedure used with old Groovy versions. The files are enumerated above but please place them in connector not global libs directory

Comment: My connector config: "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
     "plugin.name": "wal2json",
    "database.hostname": "*.*.*.*",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.password": "*******",
    "database.dbname": "ptl",
    "database.whitelist": "ptl",
     "transforms": "filter, changetopic",
    "transforms.filter.type": "io.debezium.transforms.Filter",
    "transforms.filter.language": "jsr223.groovy",
    "transforms.filter.condition": "value.after.brandid == BrandA",

Comment: I placed the three jar files in /kafka/connect/debezium-connector-postgres but got the same error and the above message was my connector configuration.

Comment: My configuration :: "transforms": "filter", "transforms.filter.type": "io.debezium.transforms.Filter", "transforms.filter.language": "jsr223.groovy", "transforms.filter.condition": "value.after.brandid == 'BrandA'" and getting error like this Caused by: io.debezium.DebeziumException: Error while evaluating expression 'value.after.brandid == BrandA'

Comment: In case of Docker, where to place these jars? Especially while `ENABLE_DEBEZIUM_SCRIPTING` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use kafka connector in order to do so?
Maybe this can be helpfull:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/filter.html

Comment: I am using Docker Debezium Kafka connector and I am not understanding how to configure in my existing environment.